# Including external Json library into project giving error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I am trying to integrate  the web service

```
http://api.punchfork.com/recipes?key=56d6e5d77b8f8f66&q=fish
```

with my project .I am following this [iPhone App Design - Loading Data From A Webservice API - Part 9 of 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ny3IZwlbfqw&t=44s) .In this tutorial i am referred to puchfork website for web service url .**This url is not working**.
  I have included json libraries

1-JSON-Url

2-JSON

These two libraries program doesn't builds and gives the following error.

1-Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Json", referenced from:

2-clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
these error occur because of highlighted lines of function

```
-(void) loadRecipes
{
    NSString *url=@"http://api.punchfork.com/recipes?key=56d6e5d77b8f8f66&q=fish";
```

> Json *myJsonParse=[[Json alloc] init];
>
> [myJsonParse startLoadingObjectWithUrl:url andDelegate:self];

```
    }
```

How i can git rid of these error ?you can download the sample project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnS0ZoTnBVN1p4WHM/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Comment: same question asked in 3rd time, are you tried in device, i think you tried in simulator,

Comment: no this question is based on web-service  ,having problem in integrating  json library ...other question is about integrating database library .they are not same they are different .

Comment: its ok are you tried in device

Comment: No i tried it in simulator only

Comment: If you paste the url in browser and it does not work, why did you expect it would work in your phone/simulator? Also, don't publish your API KEY here. It suppose to be private.

Comment: These are compile time error program does not build .it should build even without url.